# MySql Select records where date is from last month or older

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to select data where date is from last day of last month or older, so current month data should not be displayed.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE request_date ...
```

and don't know how to continue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE request_date < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
```

Anything before 12:00am on the first of the current month.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE request_date <= (curdate() - interval dayofmonth(curdate()) DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE request_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(request_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 31 DAY) >= request_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * FROM payments WHERE request_date ='".data('Y-m-t',strtotime("-1 month",time()))."'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE datediff(now(),request_date)>30
```